# Twilio video get all the rooms both with status 'in-progress' and completed

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to use twilio api with laravel, and here is my code to fetch the list of rooms.

Currently, I have to query twice with status `in-progress` and `completed` status, is there any way to get rooms with both status at the same time?

My code:

```
$twilio = new Client($this->sid, $this->token);
$rooms = $twilio->video->rooms->read(
    [
//                "type" => "group",
//                "status" => "in-progress",
        "status" => "completed"
    ],
    20
);
```

I have also tried by commenting `status` parameter and only sends with `type` param but there was no response with that.

All I want is to be fetch all rooms with both status `in-progress` and `completed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only [filter the list of rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#get-list-resource) by one room status at a time. So you need to make more than one call to fetch all of them.